# React Native Component is undefined

Tags: react-native

I want to create a new StackNavigator with 'react-navigation' package 
but when I initialize the screens for the StackNavigator i get an error -> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_TextUpload.TextUpload')

My TextUpload Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

export class TextUpload extends Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   ready: false
 }
 }

 render() {
 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text style={styles.welcome}>
       Text Upload
     </Text>
   </View>
 );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  }
});
```

My StackNavigator Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Home, Profile, Feed, Upload, Notes, TextUpload, ImageScreen } from '../components';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";
import {HOME_TAB_COLOR, FEED_TAB_COLOR, UPLOAD_TAB_COLOR, NOTE_TAB_COLOR, PROFILE_TAB_COLOR} from "../config";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: TextUpload
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need import your pages on StackNavigator page. This is how i'm using;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import Device from "../pages/device";
import DeviceScreen from "../pages/devices";

const Project= createStackNavigator({
    Measures: {
        screen: Device
    },
    Devices: {
        screen: DeviceScreen
    }
});
export default createAppContainer(Project);
```

its throw error when you import pages with curly brackets so don't use curly brackets.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I don't know why that error came earlier because I was importing other screens with curly brackets and it worked... a bit strange but it works.

Comment: you're welcome. i had same error before still don't know the reason but it works.